# Create HTML TD cell when node or attribute missing

Tags: html, xslt-1.0, apply-templates

I am working on improving on some stylesheets that I have inherited and converting them from using `<xsl:for-each>` to `<xsl:apply-templates>`. A very simplified version of one of the XML files I will be working with is:

```
<Root>
    <Row ID="123" Region="AMS">
        <First>Graham</First>
        <Last>Smith</Last>
        <Sales>12345.85</Sales>
        <Team>Team A</Team>
    </Row>
        <Row id="321">
        <First>John</First>
        <Last>Brown</Last>
        <Sales>18765.85</Sales>
        <Team>Team C</Team>
    </Row>
        <Row id="456" Region="EMEA">
        <First>Anne</First>
        <Last>Jones</Last>
        <Sales>34567.85</Sales>
        <Team>Team B</Team>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

The new stylesheet I have is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count(/*/*)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/@* | node()">
        <style>
            body * {font-family:Arial;font-size:11pt}
            table {border-collapse:collapse}
            td {border-bottom:1px solid #D8D8D8;padding:7px}
            tr.row1 {background:#F9F9F9;}
            td.tdHeader {border-bottom:2px solid #DDD;font-weight:700}
        </style>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]/@*" mode="headerAttributes" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]/*" mode="headerFields"/>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/@*" mode="headerAttributes">
        <td class="tdHeader">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*" mode="headerFields">
        <td class="tdHeader">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <tr class="row{position() mod 2}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="attributes"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="fields"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/@*" mode="attributes">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*" mode="fields">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but, due to the second node in the XML is missing the `<Region>` attribute, the cells on the result are mis-aligned, with first name now in the Region column, Last name in First name column and so on. This also happens if there is a missing child node on the Row node. for example, no team element

I have tried to test for a missing node, before calling the apply-template, and within the last two templates, but to no avail.

Any ideas? What am I missing here? I am only just starting to get my head around using apply-templates, but other methods of writing stylesheets I am fine with.

Comment: Do you really need to build the columns dynamically? I run into problems with (1) `Region` missing from `Row[1]` but present in the rest, and (2) `id` vs `ID`. (That said, you also seem to use the matches to `*` quite liberally... Try simplifying with `Root`, `Rows` and so on.)

Comment: In XSLT, it pays to be explicit. If you know in advance the names of your elements and attributes, use them. If you're trying to build an XSLT to accommodate more than one possible XML structure, then explain what is known and what isn't about the expected input.

Comment: "*I am working on improving on some stylesheets that I have inherited and converting them from using `<xsl:for-each>` to `<xsl:apply-templates>`.*" What makes you think that's necessarily an improvement?

Answer (score 0):

Provisionally, this works for your input:

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <tr class="row{position() mod 2}">
        <td><xsl:apply-templates select="@ID|@id" mode="attr2"/></td>
        <td><xsl:apply-templates select="@Region" mode="attr2"/></td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="fields"/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@ID|@id|@Region" mode="attr2">
    <b><xsl:value-of select="." /></b>
</xsl:template>
```

-- and you may remove the catch-all for `mode="attributes"`.

This forces the inclusion of a `<td>..</td>` pair even if there is no `id|ID` or `Region` attribute.

Saxon 8.8 reports an error:

> The attribute axis starting at a document-node() node will never select anything

because of your

```
<xsl:template match="/@* | node()">
```

Changing it to `<xsl:template match="node()">`, or, preferably, to `<xsl:template match="Root">` will fix this. As I said in my comment, try to use `*` as little as possible. References to `Root` and `Row` can be changed to exact matches.